# Given $W$ is a subspace of a vector space, $V$, is $W\subseteq V$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra

Generally, can a subspace of a given vector space, not be a subset of the said vector space?

Comment: it can't, a subspace is always a subset.

Comment: Remember that subspace is defined as a subset of the main vector space that is close for vector addition and scalar multiplication. 
Namely, in order for $W$ to be a subspace of $V$ it must firstly satisfies: $W \subseteq V$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally, a subspace is a subset by definition.

But here is another way in which one speaks about subspaces, which you will encounter a lot in advanced abstract algebra: Sometimes we say that $W$ is a subspace of $V$ if there is a linear map $T: W \to V$ that is injective. Indeed, then we have $W \cong T(W) \subseteq V$ and we can view $W$ as a subspace of $V$ because $V$ contains an isomorphic copy of $W$ as subspace.

Answer (score 1):

A sub*space* is necessarily a sub*set* as well. Any definition of subspace will include this. See, e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace).